# Processing cannot find library

Tags: java, jar, processing, qhull

I've tried importing from a jar file ([quickhull3d](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lloyd/java/quickhull3d.html) for example) in Processing 2.2.1 and 3.2.1 on Linux and Mac based on the instructions given [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/How-to-Install-a-Contributed-Library)

My directory structure looks like this

../Processing/Sketchbook/libraries/quickhull3d/library/quickhull3d.jar

The Processing IDE preferences set the sketchbook location to ../Processing/Sketchbook

In my .pde file, I have the opening line

```
import quickhull3d.*;
```

and I get the error:

No library found for quickhull3d
Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder.

**Note**: I have seen this question asked repeatedly both here and on the Processing forum and to the best of my ability to tell, I am following the instructions as written. I have restarted the IDE before attempting to run the sketch and I have also tried copying quickhull3d.jar to /mysketch/code, which is manually doing what the IDE would do if you were to drag and drop the file onto it.

**Follow up**: Upon further investigation, it looks like the problem is that the .jar file itself does not point to the correct locations for the xyz.class files, so I believe this may be the culprit. Additionally, I discovered that the [ComputationalGeometry](http://thecloudlab.org/processing/library.html) contributed library for Processing contains QuickHull3d, obviating the need for me to install it manually. In the future, I will make certain the paths in the .jar are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Processing editor, the easiest way to install a non-standard library is to just drag the `.jar` file onto your Processing editor. This will move the `.jar` file into your sketch folder, and you can use it just like you can use any other library.

Comment: That is equivalent to placing it in the /mysketch/code folder, which Processing will create and do if you take this path. It still does not find the library.

Comment: @GregvonWinckel It works fine for me. Make sure you've deleted the directories you created while trying to install it yourself.

Comment: I just did this and get the message: The package :quickhull3d" does not exist. You might be missing a library. In the black window it again says  Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder.

Comment: @GregvonWinckel It sounds like something to messed up with the libraries directory of your Processing. Honestly the easiest thing to do might be to uninstall all versions of Processing, delete any library directories, then reinstall Processing and try simply dragging the jar onto your PDE. That works perfectly for me, so something is messed up with your configuration.