# Cannot iimport org.gicentre.geomap.*

Tags: processing

I am using processing 3.And I am trying to add the gicentre geomap library to my processing libraries. I downloaded the geomap library from https://www.gicentre.net/geomap/. And extract it and move it under Processing/libraries. After this, I tried to run an example from this library. It just tells me that

> import org.gicentre cannot be resolved. And GeoMap class does not
>   exist.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here: [Processing cannot find library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137428/processing-cannot-find-library/40137534#40137534)

> If you're using the Processing editor, the easiest way to install a non-standard library is to just drag the `.jar` file onto your Processing editor. This will move the `.jar` file into your sketch folder, and you can use it just like you can use any other library.